# Assigning subcluster idents to original object

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat, single-cell, clustering

I have a scRNA-seq Seurat object I've analyzed, and I noticed that for some of the clusters, there's more than one cell type.

I've created a subset which and run FindClusters again to label the cell more efficiently, and now I want to "paste" the Idents I've assigned in the subcluster to the original object.

How do I do it?

Comment: Hi @ShaniS this question does look like it has been answered. Please consider upvoting and/or accepting an answer

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't shared any data or code so I will show it using the example given below,

First you need to assign a specific cluster to the cells which are having another type like C_new.

```
cells_df <- data.frame(row.names=paste0("Cell", 1:10, sep = ""),as.vector(paste0("C",1:10,sep="")))

colnames(cells_df) <- "clusters"


cluster_new <- c("Cell6","Cell2")


cells_df$clusters <- as.character(cells_df$clusters)

for(i in 1:length(cluster_new)) {
j <- cluster_new[i] 
cells_df[j,] <- "C_new"
}

head(cells_df)
         clusters
 Cell1       C1
 Cell2    C_new
 Cell3       C3
 Cell4       C4
 Cell5       C5
 Cell6    C_new
```

And if you have already assigned new clusters to the cells then you can skip the above step. Now save the new cluster belongings into the seurat object using the `Idents` function

```
Idents(seurat_obj) <- cells_df$clusters
```

Then you can perform the differential gene expression as follows, for example if you want to find the differentially expressed genes between cluster `C7` vs `C_new` you can do it as follows,

```
FindMarkers(seurat_obj,ident.1 = "C7", ident.2 = "C_new" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `parentObj` is the original seurat object, and `tmp_subset` is your subset, you can

```r
new_metadata <- parentObj@meta.data 
tmp_subset_annotation <- tmp_subset@meta.data 

# new_metadata
           original_annotation
ATTCGGA-1   TCD4
AAATAAA-1   TCD4-naive
...

# tmp_subset_annotation
           new_cellType
ATTCGGA-1   TCD4-naive
AAATAAA-1   TCD4-naive
...

new_metadata$refined_annotation <- sapply(rownames(new_metadata), 
     function(ita) ifelse(ita %in% rownames(tmp_subset_annotation),
            tmp_subset_annotation[match(ita,rownames(tmp_subset_annotation)),"new_cellType"],
            new_metadata[match(ita,rownames(new_metadata)),"original_annotation"]))
```

Basically you iterate each rownames of the original object, and assign the new annotation, if the UMI matches a UMI in the subset, otherwise you keep the original annotation.

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error saying

Error in ans[npos] <- rep(no, length.out = len)[npos] : 
  replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In rep(no, length.out = len) :

Comment: You should add the first few lines of both metadata tables (e.g. `head(object@metadata)`). Without seeing the data it is difficult to help.

Comment: I added a new question with my actual code - https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/18365/integrating-subcluster-idents-with-original-object

Comment: You should edit your original question rather than create a new thread. Especially because you are asking exactly the same thing.